# Geolocation locates same location multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

SCRIPT

```
/*get geo location*/

var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var y = document.getElementById("demo2");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
   /* x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  */
    x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
    y.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;

    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+"&sensor=false";

$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    $(".place").empty();
    $(".place").css("display","block");
    //console.log("JSON Data: " + json.results);
    $.each(json.results, function (index, value) {
        $.each(value.address_components, function (index, value) {
            console.log(index + ': ' + value.long_name);
            //alert(value.long_name);
            localStorage.long_name = value.long_name;
            console.log(localStorage.long_name);
            $(".place").append(localStorage.long_name+", ");
           //this line runs query to fetch users matching the places above
            displayTutor(value.long_name);

        });
    });
});
}
```

> //This line shows the list of places retrieved by geolocation

```
 $(".place").append(localStorage.long_name+", ");
```

This is the places retrieved

[image]

See the same places returned few times like 'selangor', 'malaysia' and so forth. I think, this cause the below query return same user from the places few times.

Query

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM usrinfo, posts WHERE usrinfo.UUID = posts.UUID AND posts.location LIKE '%$this->place%' GROUP BY usrinfo.UUID";
```

It could be that, making this function call `displayTutor(value.long_name);` within $each loop
causes the same result fetched again and again.

The function makes ajax call to the query

```
function displayTutor(param){   
    $('#contents').empty();
    $("#titleBox_content > p").text("Tutors > "+param);
    $('#contents').append("<table><tr>");
    var globalStore = {};
    globalStore.data = [];
    var data;
    var getUrl;
    getUrl = '/search/getLocation.php?place='+param,
    $.when(
    // 1st query
    $.get(getUrl,function(data){globalStore.data = globalStore.data.concat(data);console.log(data)},"json")
).then(function() {
    console.log(globalStore.data);
................................
.................................
```

Now, I need not the result same result to repeat. How to do that, please?

> EDIT
>
> I found that my query doesn't return any error as I tried in
>   phpmyadmin console and it doesn't return any duplicate entries. In
>   fact in the browser, for the first 2 seconds or so, it shows the
>   correct results without repeating, but after that the same results
>   added up. It's like the ajax call made for more than four times by the
>   function placed within $.each loop as above.
>
> Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: `FROM userinfo, posts ... WHERE tableA... = tableB...` is an _old_ and deprecated `OUTER JOIN` form then yes, you're getting duplicates. You'd better use `RIGHT JOIN` (dropping that IMO awful syntax).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, I'll surely take your advice and amend that query. But do you have any idea on the geolocation part that throws duplicate entries? Because this is urgent !

Comment: You're performing an OUTER JOIN, if an user has multiple posts then yes...you'll have duplicates. It has nothing to do (as far as I can see) with geolocation.